# What is this notation for a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I was working on a statistical subject and we consider a vector $z\in\mathbb{R}^d$, at some point we want to distinguish the k first elements of this vector, thus the author wrote $z$ as
$z'=[z_{1}^{'} z_{2}^{'}]$ where $z_{1}^{'}$ represents the k first elements of interest. However I don't know what is the nature of $z'$, is this a "matrix notation" in order to cut a vector in two "subset" ?

Thank you a lot

Comment: I don't see the added benefit of introducing the prime. $z=[z_1 z_2]$ is doing the job just fine with $z_1 \in \mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: With regards to "cutting a vector in half" like this... if the context is such that this is a useful thing to do, then go ahead.  So long as the notation and intention is clear, there is nothing wrong with introducing new otherwise unknown notation to accomplish this.  There is precedent for doing this as well, for instance see [Block Matrices on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formal answer is as follows: the vector spaces $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbb{R}^{k}\times \mathbb{R}^{d-k}$ are canonically isomorphic (as vector spaces). This means that both vector spaces represent essentially the same vector space, so the elements of $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be identified uniquely with elements of $\mathbb{R}^{k}\times \mathbb{R}^{d-k}$ and viceversa. This mean that for every $v\in \mathbb{R}^d$ there is a unique $v'\in \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^{d-k}$ that represents canonically $v$, where $v'=(v_1,v_2)$ for some $v_1\in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $v_2\in \mathbb{R}^{d-k}$.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I have seen the notion of isomorphic vector space but never when it comes to a vector space isomorph to a product vector space. This means that there exists a bijective linear mapping that takes element from  $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^{k}\times\mathbb{R}^{d-k}$ it looks interesting I should study that further to make it clear. How do we know that it means that an element of $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be identified uniquely with elements of $\mathbb{R}^{k}\times\mathbb{R}^{d-k}$ ?

Comment: @coboy the canonical map is given by $(v_1,\ldots ,v_d)\mapsto ((v_1,\ldots ,v_k),(v_{k+1},\ldots ,v_d))$

Comment: Oh yes !! Since the image of a basis of a linear mapping is also a basis in the case of an isomoprhism. Just here we have a product space as space of arrival, but one obtains well a base of each of the spaces? Thank you a lot Masacroso !!